# Azure API Management and ASMX/WSDL SOAP endpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, api, azure, azure-api-management

I have an old SOAP api that uses an ASMX endpoint, will Azure API Management be able to recognize and interface with it?

Comment: SOAP Passthrough is now available and SOAP2REST is coming very soon.

Answer (score 3):

There are more people interested in this feature: [feedback.azure.com](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/5782547-soap-support). This is currently not supported however.

Answer (score 1):

Support for pass-through SOAP endpoints was added recently: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/general-availibility-azure-api-management-soap-pass-through/

SOAP-to-REST scenarios are also possible using policies: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2016/12/14/soap-to-rest/