# Is there a reason azure-api-management doesn't allow the expose SOAP services?

Tags: web-services, soap, azure-api-management

I am benchmarking different API management solutions and Azure API Management is one of them. One of my criterion is to be able to import a soap web service and to "restify" it.

After some researches in the msdn doc it seems that it is not possible to import a SOAP service whereas it has been asked by the community almost two years ago: [This thread](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/5782547-soap-support) has been marked as "under review" for almost 2 years.

I am pretty surprised to see that this is not possible whereas SOAP web services are still pretty common and I think it would be useful to a lot of people to be able to manage them in Azure.

So I have two questions:

- Is it really still impossible to manage SOAP web services in Azure or has this feature been added and I didn't look at the right place for a documentation?
- If it is still not possible, why? What explains that Microsoft still doesn't allow to do that?

**Note** That I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637002/azure-api-management-and-asmx-wsdl-soap-endpoint/28299153#28299153) two things motivated my question: the other one hasn't been active for more than one year and it doesn't explain the reason why SOAP endpoint are not available.

Comment: It is possible to channel simple SOAP calls through Azure API management, we use this, just no import.

Comment: @ErikOppedijk: Thanks for this information, could you link me to some documentation about that, I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: For instance this article: http://mostlydotnetdev.blogspot.nl/2015/03/azure-api-management-apim-consuming.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently we don't offer support for SOAP in Azure API Management; however, it is an area under review. The best way to help us ensure it is prioritized correctly and has the features you need would be to put your thoughts down on the Azure Feedback site (that you linked to earlier). We would be really interested to learn more about what you need and how you would see it working.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/5782547-soap-support

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a subsidiary question: is it possible to have an idea of how the review is going? Like when it will be decided to include the feature or not.

Comment: Hi Statox, I can't give you specifics at this point, other than to say that feedback and feature ideas are greatly appreciated and considered.